# Microsoft Reporting Services: hide footer depending on export format?

Tags: reporting-services, format, export, ssrs-2008

I'm using Microsoft Reporting Services (MSRS) 2008. Currently I'm designing reports that can be rendered both as PDF and Exel, which works fine in general.

If I define a footer in the designer, I'll see it in PDF and do not see it on the Excel sheet.
Although when I print out the Excel file, the footer is there again (in the page preview also).

*Is there any way to tell MSRS to hide/not include the footer if Excel is chosen as output format?* I want to have it in PDF and I don't want it in Excel. Designing two reports would be a way to achieve that, but a most unconvenient one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sql server 208 R2 you can achieve this behavior using the RenderFormat Global Variable. I don't think this is possible in prior versions.

http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/03/03/sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-as-you-like-it/